# Spring data and query methods

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data

I'm new in Spring data and I'm studying how to use it.
I thought that I need two type of query:
1)Simple query that I can obtain with query methods like this

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Integer> {
    List<Car> findByid_Fleet(int idFleet);
}
```

but I obtain Invalid derived query! No property fleet found for type String! Traversed path: Car.id.
In car table there is id_fleet, a foreign key.

2)I need complex query, how can I write them?
My code is so structured (example for one domain class):

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Integer> {
        List<Car> findByid_Fleet(int idFleet);
    }
```

car services

```
public interface CarServices extends GeneralServices<Car, Integer>{

    /**
     * Return list of cars for one fleet
     * @param idFleet
     * @return
     */
    public List<Car> findCarsByIdFleet(int idFleet);

}
```

carServicesImpl

```
@Service
public class CarServicesImpl implements CarServices {
    @Resource
    private CarRepository carRepository;

    @Override
    public Car create(Car car) {
        return carRepository.save(car);
    }

    @Override
    public Car findById(Integer id) {
        return carRepository.getOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean exists(Integer id) {
        return carRepository.exists(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Car> findCarsByIdFleet(int idFleet) {

        return carRepository.findByid_Fleet(idFleet);
    }
}
```

and database services where I group my database method

```
@Service
public class DatabaseFleetsAndCarsServicesImpl implements DatabaseFleetsAndCarsServices {
    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseFleetsAndCarsServicesImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    private CarServices carServices;
    @Autowired
    private FleetServices fleetServices;

    @Override
    public List<Fleet> getFleets() {        
        return fleetServices.getFleets();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Car> getCars(int idFleet) {
        return carServices.findCarsByIdFleet(idFleet);
    }
}
```

Part of my car class:

```
/**
 * Car generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "car", catalog = "ATS")
public class Car implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer idCar;
    private CarType carType;
    private Fleet fleet;
    private String id;
    private int initialKm;
    private String carChassis;
    private String note;
    private Set<Acquisition> acquisitions = new HashSet<Acquisition>(0);
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question : you don't put the foreign key name as the method name, but the name of the member : in your car class, you have a field named Fleet and in Fleet class, a field named idFleet ?
then the name should be :

```
`List<Car> findByFleetIdFleet(int idFleet);`
```

And for the second question, you need a custom repository where you will implement those "complex" queries :

1 - `public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Integer>, CarRepositoryCustom`

2 - `public interface CarRepositoryCustom`

3 - `public class CarRepositoryImpl implements CarRepositoryCustom`

in the custom interface, just declare methods ... and in the class, implement them .. spring will do some magic (proxying interfaces / classes by name) and your custom queries will be available

code in custom class should be like this :

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public List<Car> findAllCars() {
  String jpql = "select c from Car c";
  Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
  return query.getResultList();
}
```

(and with parameter) :

```
public List<Car> findAllByCarChassis(String chassis) {
      String jpql = "select c from Car c where c.carChassis = :chassisParam";

      Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
      query.setParameter("chassisParam", chassis);

      return query.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: that error , I have Fleet object  in my car class. So I have to retrieve Fleet by id and put this object into findByFleet method?

Comment: no, just name your method : findByFleetId ... it will first check the member Fleet in Car class, end then check Id member in Fleet class ...

Comment: if I use List<Car> findByFleetId(int idFleet); I receive Invalid derived query! No property id found for type Fleet! Traversed path: Car.fleet.

Comment: do you have a property id in your Fleet class ?

Comment: I had to rename List<Car> findByFleetIdFleet(int idFleet); because Fleet has idFleet....it is correct?

Comment: thanks, for the second question could you give me an example of query?(also stupid query)

Comment: i'll update my answer .. (hoping that you have configured the entitymanager in spring files)

Comment: Isnt it better to just create the custom query inside the repository? `@Query("select c from Car where c.carChassis = ?1")
List<Car> getCarListByChassis(String carChassis);`

Comment: this is not my query, I would have to retrieve Fleet by idFleet and then the cars by Fleet

Comment: @Pras thanks for the example, only one error into String jpql, i forgot to insert from Car c